# Is white space significant in GraphQL or not?

Tags: graphql

In GraphQL, white space appears to be significant since it separates tokens:

```
{
  human(id: "1000") {
    name
    height
  }
}
```

However, the [spec says](https://spec.graphql.org/June2018/#sec-White-Space) that white space is not significant, and doesn't specify how tokens, names, and so forth are separated.

I think newlines might be critical in separating `name` and `height` in the above example. Is it valid to delete the newline and have them on the same line, separated by a space or tab? I assume the indentation is insignificant? Is this valid GraphQL, and is it exactly equivalent to the above?:

```
{human(id: "1000") {name height}}
```

Obviously, it would break if we eliminated the space between `name` and `height`, so spaces seem to matter. Since GraphQL doesn't use commas, should the spec specify that white space is significant?

Answer (score 7):

From the spec (emphasis mine):

> White space is used to improve legibility of source text and **act as separation between tokens**, and any amount of white space may appear before or after any token. White space between tokens is not significant **to the semantic meaning of a GraphQL Document**, however white space characters may appear within a String or Comment token.

In other words, white space (or any other [ignored token](https://spec.graphql.org/June2018/#sec-Source-Text.Ignored-Tokens)) needs to be used to separate tokens. But it does not have semantic meaning itself and is therefore not significant.

Spaces, tabs, new lines and commas are all ignored tokens and can be used interchangeably to separate tokens. The following snippets are semantically equivalent and all valid syntax:

```
name height
```

```
name   height
```

```
name,height
```

```
name
height
```

```
name ,  ,,,,
,, height
```

What token you use is ultimately up to you, however you should always keep readability in mind.

Comment: Thanks. What's with the commas in a couple of your examples? Are they covered in the spec?

Comment: The section I already linked as well as [this](https://spec.graphql.org/June2018/#Comma)

Comment: Got it. On the white space, I guess I don't understand what it means for something to be required, but at the same time "ignored", "insignificant", and not semantically meaningful. I would describe it differently since it's required to separate tokens.

By the way, the spec doesn't say new lines can be used to separate tokens. It only defines tabs and spaces as "white space" in that section. It's ambiguous in the "line terminators" section. The topic of how tokens are separated should be called out explicitly and they should just say what can be used.

Comment: So your fourth example, with the new lines only, shouldn't work, per the spec. It just says that new lines are used to improve legibility. It doesn't say that they separate tokens, the way it says so with white space and commas (where "white space" is horizontal tabs and spaces.) https://spec.graphql.org/June2018/#sec-Line-Terminators

Comment: Again, the ignored token section specifies that ignored tokens are used to separate lexical tokens and line terminators are ignored tokens. The fact that the line terminator section doesn't spell this out doesn't negate what's stated a few paragraphs down. If you have suggestions for how to make the spec clearer, you're welcome to open an issue or PR against the repo.

Comment: The ignored token section doesn't say anything about separating lexical tokens – the word "separate" doesn't appear at all. In any case, I don't think specs should be written in a way that requires readers to pick up stray morsels from different sections and weave them into inferences about basic rules. Specs should be clear and direct, with basic rules explicitly laid out in a freestanding way. I'll submit a PR.

Comment: if I attempt to submit a query via CURL and I have carriage returns and/or linefeeds in the query I get an error `"error": "must have query", "link": "http://some stuff here"` but if I remove all CRLF from my posted data it works